# Instantiating a generic class (Java)

Tags: generics, java-7, instantiation, type-inference, diamond-operator

I have always been taught that when instantiating a generic class in your code to do it like so:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But when I'm working in Eclipse it always auto-completes it to this:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList <>();
```

Is there a difference between these two statements?

Comment: You should really be doing it like this: `List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();` -- program against the interface, not the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is simply shortcut syntax (known as *type inference*) in Java 7.

See [*Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList <>();
```

In this case type inference isapplied.Thhus you don't need to explicitly declare the **parameterized type** while constructor invokation.